# WebAPI2 Model Binding not working with HTTP PUT

Tags: ajax, http, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm following Scott Allen's MVC4 course on PluralSight (I'm using MVC5 and WebAPI2 but they *should* be the same) and I am trying to pass an object via HTTP PUT. The model binder should bind it, but I am getting NULL for the parameter.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PutObjective(int id, [FromBody] Objective objective)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && id == objective.ObjectiveID)
        {
            //todo: update - look up id, replace text
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objective);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }  
    }
```

and in my front-end javascript I am doing the following (I'm creating an object for testing, so ignore 'objective' passed in):

```
        var updateObjective = function (objective) {

        var myobj = { "ObjectiveID": "3", "ObjectiveDescription": "test" };

        return $.ajax(objectiveApiUrl + "/" + objective.ObjectiveID, {
            type: "PUT",
            data: myobj
        });
    }
```

My class looks like this:

```
    public class Objective
{
    public int ObjectiveID { get; private set; }
    public string ObjectiveDescription { get; set; }
    public Objective (int Id, string Desc)
    {
        this.ObjectiveID = Id;
        this.ObjectiveDescription = Desc;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why 'objective' in the backend is always 'null' ?
I've done what Scott Allen is doing, even tried adding in [FromBody] but no luck. $.ajax should have the correct content type by default I understand, so no need to set it.

I had Fiddler2 but I'm unsure as to what I am looking at to be honest. I can see my object as JSON being sent to the backend.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have resolved it. I'll leave the question unanswered for the moment to see if anybody can guess what the problem is (and probably explain it better than  I can).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're familiar with Model Binding you'll have seen the issue in my Objective class:

```
public int ObjectiveID { get; private set; }
```

with a private set, no instance can be created of the Objective class. To make it work, the 'private' access specifier needs to be removed.

What needs to happen really is that Objective becomes ObjectiveViewModel, and we convert what comes back to an Objective domain object (which may have more properties than we need for this screen). This can have a private set.